# Let $X,Y,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. and $\phi(x,y)$ a test function. Does $\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}\phi(X_i,X_j)\to\mathbb E\phi(X,Y)$ a.s.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we are given a distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$, and a smooth function $\phi:\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ with compact support. Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $\mu$. Then is it the case that
$$
\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^N\phi(X_i,X_j)\to\int_{\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d}\!\phi(x,y)\,\mathrm d\mu(x)\,\mathrm d\mu(y)?
$$
For single-variable $\phi$, this is just the strong law of large numbers, but I don't quite see how to prove it here.

Comment: Can't you use integration by parts and the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem?  Write the sum as the double integral of the emipirical cdf against some mixed partial derivative of $\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \frac{\sum_{i,j}\phi(X_i,X_j)}{N^2}$. Since $\phi$ is smooth and defined on a compact support, it is bounded by some $k \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Therefore, for every $i$, 
$|f(X_1,\ldots,X_i,\ldots,X_n)-f(X_1,\ldots,X_i^*,\ldots,X_n)|
\leq \frac{2k}{n}$. It follows from [McDiarmid's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob_martingale#McDiarmid's_inequality) that

$$P(|f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-E[f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)]| \geq \epsilon) 
\leq 2\exp(-0.5\epsilon^2k^{-1}n)$$

Also observe that
$\theta_n := E[f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)] = \frac{nE[\phi(X_1,X_1)] + n(n-1)E[\phi(X_1,X_2)]}{n^2}$ and $\theta := E[\phi(X_1,X_2)] = \lim_n \theta_n$.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}P(|f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-\theta| \geq \epsilon) 
&\leq \sum_{n}P(|f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-\theta_n| \geq \epsilon - |\theta_n-\theta|) \\
&\leq \sum_n 2\exp(-0.5(\epsilon - |\theta_n-\theta|)^2k^{-1}n) < \infty
\end{align*}

It follows from Borel-Cantelli that $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ converges a.s. to $\theta$.

Comment: +1.  This proof relies on the existence of the bound $k$.  Can you comment on, or perhaps even better give a counter-example, where $\phi$ is unbounded in such a way that $f()$ does not converge to $\theta$?  E.g., I would imagine $E[f()]$ still converges to $\theta$ (even if $\phi$ is not bounded) so any counterexample may only violate convergence a.s.?

Comment: For example, if  $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ and $\phi(x,y) = xy^{-1}$, then $\phi(X_i,X_j) \sim Cauchy$ for every $i \neq j$. Therefore, $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ does not converge.

Comment: However, note that OP states that $\phi$ is smooth and has a compact support. Therefore, $\phi$ is bounded.

Comment: I understand that the OP stmt implies $\phi$ is bounded, and your proof is correct.  I was just wondering what examples of unbounded $\phi$ would make the convergence false.  Thanks for bringing up Cauchy -- it is an interesting example.  In that case, does RHS $= 0$ (by symmetry?), or is RHS also undefined?  If RHS is undefined, this example generalizes to any $\phi$ with an undefined mean.  I was more wondering if there is a case where e.g. RHS is defined and finite, but LHS either does not converge, or converges to a different value.

Comment: My application actually involves a $\phi$ which has a pole, and then bounding the error — but if there’s any technique using a direct bound, I’d be very interested.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine - if $\phi$ has a pole, it might be possible that $E[\phi(X_1, X_2)]$ is finite but $E[\phi(X_1, X_1)] = +\infty$...  This may open up the possibility that $\sum_{i=1}^N \phi(X_i, X_i) \to c N^2$?  And further that LHS and RHS are both finite but unequal...?

Comment: Yes, we would need the measure $\mu$ to be sufficiently regular, say, in $L^\infty$.

Comment: The same result should hold whenever there is a finite constant $B$ such that $E[\phi(X_i,X_j)^2] \leq B$ for all $i,j$ (including $i=j$).  It may also hold if we only require $E[|\phi(X_i,X_j)|]\leq B$ for all $i,j$ but that would require a lot more work.

Comment: I think there are cases where convergence occurs even if $E[|\phi(X_i,X_i)|]=\infty$.